# is_file() and local file inclusion vulnerability

Tags: php, security

I am helping my friend to secure his website. He gave me source files and I found something which, in my opinion, may cause many problems, but, as before, my friend says what this part of code is secure :

```
if(is_file('foo/' . $_POST['f'] . '/bar/foo.php'))
  {
    include('foo/' . $_POST['f'] . '/bar/foo.php');
  }
```

I have demonstrated him that I can bypass `include()` function, but he says that, with `is_file()` this part of code is 100% secure, please help me to demonstrate him that the code is not secure, or to convince me that this code is secure.

This Code Bypasses `include()` function (WINDOWS):

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'f=../foo/bar.php' . str_repeat('.', 4086)); // without is_file() check this request leads to LFI
```

but `is_file()` still returns false

Comment: It's not exploitable, but why is this code even here? What use case prompts you to load PHP files like this?

Comment: There's an if check for `is_file` so it won't throw anything. The only thing he can by pass is not including the file.

Comment: I think its better to check `$_POST['f'];` because the hacker can use it to include file from a different location like `'foo'.'/../foo2'.'/bar/foo.php'` and also maybe this `'foo'.'/../foo2/someFileWhichWillCauseProblem.php?'.'/bar/foo.php'` whick cause to include `'foo'.'/../foo2/someFileWhichWillCauseProblem.php` with an extra parameter `?/bar/foo.php`. which is dangerous. so its strongle recommended that you dont do that.

Comment: @imsiso, i tried to add "?" but is_file() check works as before. It returns false, so, in which cases "?" will work?. PHP returns :  failed to open stream: Invalid argument

Comment: @imsiso foo/../thisFileExists.php?/bar/foo.php

Comment: @imsi Local file paths don't contain, support or parse `?`, that's only relevant in URLs! You cannot include a local file "with parameters".

Answer (score 2):

Avoid usage of such construction. If attacker would be able to put his own PHP file on server (even outside of WWW root, for instance, in tmp folder), he would be able to execute it with permissions of web server.

Comment: Thanks, so you think that someone can bypass is_file() check, right?

Comment: yes in addition to @Nickolay Olshevsky I should say like uploading a file with harmful code as an Image.(with .jpg , .png , etc. extension)

Comment: Yes, if he would be able to put his file on server. That's just easy to write switch() or bunch of if's to select one of the needed files.

Answer (score 2):

If the file did not exist, `include` would not include it anyway. Putting an `is_file` check before it is redundant and doesn't add any security. As noted, including arbitrary files based on user input is **always** a bad idea and a security flaw; whether you double check that the file exists or not.

Answer (score 2):

`is_file` and `include` had a flaw where it was possible to [prematurely end the string by using a null byte](http://php.net/security.filesystem.nullbytes).

So depending on the PHP version, having a POST with the following may print out any arbitrary file:

```
f=../../../../../etc/passwd%00
```

Only since PHP 5.3.4 all file system functions are said to be immune to null byte poisoning.

Comment: It is also possible to exploit this using Windows’ Alternative Data Streams: With `foo:bar`, `foo` is referenced by the data stream name `bar`. So `f=../../../../../boot.ini:` may work as well.

Answer (score 1):

> my friend says what this part of code is secure

If your friend is the authority - and having you asking the question here that way sounds a bit like he is - you should better listen to him and follow his path - right or wrong. That's what friends are for: We allow to have mistakes each other.

Apart from that, create a whitelist for allowed values in `$_POST['f']` to end any discussion. Doing so would require you to formulate exact specifications what qualifies a valid path here and what not.

You can not bring security to an argument when it is not clear what you want to secure.